# How to zip only files and not the full path

Tags: perl, cgi

I'm trying to zip up image files using Archive::Zip. The files are in Data/Temp/Files When I loop through the logs in the directory and add them to the zip file, I end up with the folder hierarchy and the image files when I only want the image files.

So the zip ends up containing:

```
Data
  └Temp  
    └Files
       └Image1.jpg
        Image2.jpg
        Image3.jpg
```

When I want the zip file to contain is:

```
Image1.jpg
Image2.jpg
Image3.jpg
```

Here is the script I'm running to test with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Archive::Zip;

$obj = Archive::Zip->new();   # new instance

@files = <Data/Temp/Files/*>;

foreach $file (@files) {
    $obj->addFile($file);   # add files
}

$obj->writeToFileNamed("Data/Temp/Files/Images.zip");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) to change into the directory:

```
use Archive::Zip;

$obj = Archive::Zip->new();   # new instance

chdir 'Data/Temp/Files';
@files = <*>;

foreach $file (@files) {
    $obj->addFile($file);   # add files
}

$obj->writeToFileNamed("Images.zip");
```

Answer (score 2):

The names and paths of zip archive members are completely independent of those of their real file counterparts. Although the two names are conventionally the same, `AddFile` allows you to specify a second parameter which is the name and path of the corresponding archive member where the file information should be stored

You can achieve the effect you're asking for my using `basename` from the `File::Basename` module to extract just the file name from the complete path

This program demonstrates. Note that it is *essential* to `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip;
use File::Basename 'basename';

my $zip = Archive::Zip->new;

for my $jpg ( glob 'Data/Temp/Files/*.jpg' ) {
  $zip->addFile($jpg, basename($jpg));
}

$zip->writeToFileNamed('Data/Temp/Files/Images.zip');
```